# What is the rule in Java for 'pass by reference' / 'pass by value' for variable assignment?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So it's well documented how methods work with parameter passing with regards to pass by reference/ pass by value, but what about with variable assignment?

For example, I just wrote some code that looks like:

```
TreeNode<T> parent = null;
TreeNode<T> current = m_root;
while(current != null) {
    parent = current;
    current = current.getRight();
}
```

Now, how do I know that `parent` is not equal to `current.getRight()` after the last assignment in the `while` loop? What is the rule?

Comment: How do you know that `null` is not equal to `current` after the *first* assignment in the `while` loop?

Comment: The rule is very simple: always pass-by-value, and pass-by-reference does not exist in Java. But: references are also passed by value. Note that passing a reference by value is not the same as pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the rule in Java for 'pass by reference' / 'pass by value' for variable assignment?

The same as for passing things into methods: **Values** are copied, there is no reference to the variable.

> Now, how do I know that `parent` is not equal to `current.getRight()` after the last assignment in the `while` loop? What is the rule?

You don't, they could both be `null`. But if one of them *isn't* `null`, you know they're not equal, because the loop continues until `current` is `null` and so if `parent` isn't `null`, they can't be equal.

But beware confusion here. The values that `parent` and `current` can hold are object references. (The "reference" in that sentence has ***nothing*** to do with the "reference" in "pass-by-reference". It's just that the word "reference" is used for many different things in different contexts.) So both of those variables can *refer to* the same object, by having the same value (the same object reference) in both variables.

This is exactly the same for variables as for method arguments. Let's use a simpler example:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = a;
```

We have one `Foo` object in memory, and both the `a` and `b` variables contain the same value, which is a reference to that object. But there is **no** connection between the two variables. So for instance, if we add this:

```
b = new Foo();
```

...now we have two `Foo` objects in memory, and `a` refers to (points to) one of them, and `b` refers to the other. Doing that has no effect at all on the value in `a`. (Exactly the way it would be if `a` and `b` were `int`s.)

Comment: If after setting `Foo b = a`, I was to write `b.bar = 2;`, would this also change what value `a.bar` returns?

Comment: @KeirSimmons: Mostly correct, yes. It doesn't *also* change it, it just changes it. In that situation, `b.bar` and `a.bar` are the **same** property. Imagine two people looking at a piece of paper with a circle on it. Then one of the people writes the number 2 in the circle. The other person sees the 2. The people are the references (`a` and `b`); the paper is the object; the circle is the property; the 2 is the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that might help show how pass by value/reference works:

http://blog.aaronshaw.net/2014/02/13/java-is-always-pass-by-value/

I'd put it in a comment but they're harder to notice.